# How get the collection’s entry ID through a Relation in Strapi?

Tags: strapi

I hope you’re doing well.

So, I’m creating a database-driven website about Portuguese dubs and using Strapi as backend and CMS.
I created a collection type name Movies that has, amongst other things, a repeatable component for the cast.
This repeatable component is made of a relations component with the Voice Actors collection (one to one) and a text field with the character he played.

When I call the API for a certain movie and populate Cast, it retrieves me the cast. However, it retrieves me the wrong ID for the Voice Actor.

For example, my Voice Actors’ ID go from 16 to 20, whoever the API is returning 10, 11, 12…

How do I retrieve the Voice Actors’ ID?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so let's make it clear you have a collection `movies`, witch has repeatable components `casts` witch has relation to an `actor`.

So id that you have in your screenshot is likely an id of component, to get full data you would need to populate at list two levels deep:

```js
  const query = qs.stringify(
    {
      populate: {
        casts: {
          populate: ['actor'],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      encodeValuesOnly: true,
    }
  );
```

witch would give request like this:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/movies?populate[casts][populate][0]=actor
```

Comment: Meanwhile, I actually managed to get it by calling: http://localhost:8080/api/movies/14?populate=Cast.actor, but I was trying to do like you did. I read the documentation part about populating several levels, but I still don't fully understand it, specially the [0]. As soon as I test your answer, I'll mark it as solved. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, the [0] is representation of array compiled by `qs` stringify, populate takes `object` or `array of strings` as argument. you can try this page, the populate part should be exactly the same https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/entity-service/populate.html#basic-populating

Comment: Also on strapi Discord there is `best-practices-archive` channel, there is Populating via rest video, that should make it really clear